# Generating HTML documentation site from "mark down (.md)" files

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, r-markdown

Is there something similar to "**maven site plugin (javadoc)**" is available for node? To be more specific, we are looking for a node package which can covert .md files in a reactjs project into html files. By convention each folder of our project has a markdown file which holds detailed documentation. We are looking for a tool (cli) which we can fire during the build process to create a documentation folder in the build (destination directory)- specifically interested in static HTML generation.

Thanks,
San

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found https://react-styleguidist.js.org/docs/documenting.html for my project. Awesome tool (though it is not equivalent to Maven Site).

Answer (score 1):

What have you looked for so far? Just googling "node MD to HTML" gives plenty of potential modules like [this one](https://github.com/andris9/node-markdown) and [this one](https://github.com/showdownjs/showdown).

Have you tried some and they haven't worked? What have you looked for?

Comment: I have done a quick research on the available tools/module for our requirement. But couldn't find any which can match the site plugin for maven. It would be ideal if there is node module with tout of the box capability search all folders  for convert all the .md files into HTML files during build. It seems showdown and ember-cli-showdown are powerful, but it cannot be compared with site plugin. Thanks

Comment: Well if worse comes to worse, if those modules (or any other command line tools) have the ability to convert MD to HTML then having a simple shell script that crawls through your directories and converts any MD files it finds into HTML files and puts them in your 'documentation' folder shouldn't be hard. The shell script would only be a few lines in total. Then in your package.json you can tell npm to run that script during the build process. I find I have to do that sometimes with certain non-standard files